# Python/xrld Read rows and columns

Tags: python, xlrd

I have exel file with specific structure.
There are first row is title second are names and the last one are values.
I need take only title and values it is not so difficult if Excel file has only 3 rows, but it can be 100 rows and columms and i need to get only Title and values, not any names and empty rows

```
         1          2        3           
1    GroupOne     Empty      Empty
2      Jonh       Elena     Mike    
3        45         100      500 
4        Empty      Empty     Empty
5   GroupTwo       Empty     Empty
6   Lisa           Ken       Lui
7   100             300      400
```

And etc.

As You see between two Title always is one Empty row.
Finaly it will be something like this:

```
GroupOne
45   100   500
GroupTwo
100 300 400
```

Thank you in advance. I would be so grateful for some help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this [website](http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2012/03/examples-reading-excel-xls-documents-using-pythons-xlrd/) has an example that will help you:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('my_workbook.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
num_cells = worksheet.ncols - 1
curr_row = -1
while curr_row < num_rows:
  curr_row += 1
  row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
  print 'Row:', curr_row
  curr_cell = -1
  while curr_cell < num_cells:
    curr_cell += 1
    # Cell Types: 0=Empty, 1=Text, 2=Number, 3=Date, 4=Boolean, 5=Error, 6=Blank
    cell_type = worksheet.cell_type(curr_row, curr_cell)
    cell_value = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row, curr_cell)
    print ' ', cell_type, ':', cell_value
```

The function `cell_type` should help you build a if-statement such as `if worksheet.cell_type != 0` and thus skip empty cells.

Comment: Please update the link. It's now showing `404` error.